# Angular/Ionic $http post error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send a API request to our API but the $http.post is not working / returning a Cannot read property 'data' of undefined error.

Any suggestions on how to do this or workarounds? or how to properly debug the problem?.

**Code :**

```
var data = {
    from: "xxxx@gmail.com",
    to: "yyyyy@gmail.com",
    content_type: "text/plain",
    body: "Temp Message",
    date: "2017-09-12T03:48:29.285Z",
};

var config = {
    headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + "u/xx/yyy:zzz",
    }
}

return $http.post('https://xxx/send', data, config)
.success(function (data, status, header, config) {
    console.log("SUCCESS");
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    console.log("FAILED");
});
```

**Angular / Ionic Error**

```
0     330020   error    TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24536:24
    at processQueue (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29132:28)
    at http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29148:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30400:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30216:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30508:24)
    at done (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24829:47)
    at completeRequest (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25027:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestError (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24978:9)
```

Comment: it seems you are trying to get `data` property from any object which is undefined, but that code not here provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` of your HTTP POST request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Thus the `data` should be serialized as parameter format, using `$.param()` for example.

For your code, it would look like:

```
...
data = $.param(data); // using jQuery to serialze JSON as parameters.
return $http.post('https://xxx/send', data, config)
    .success(function (data, status, header, config) {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        console.log("FAILED");
    });
```

Or, if the server actually accept JSON format, the `Content-Type` should be changed to `application/json`. The code would look like:

```
...
var config = {
  headers : {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + "u/xx/yyy:zzz",
  }
}
...
return $http.post('https://xxx/send', JSON.stringify(data), config)
  ...
```